# What is the way to test the conditions inside the constructor with gtest?

Tags: c++, constructor, googletest

My class's constructor opens a file and reads some data from it. The constructor does not take any argument.

The file opening part has to be done inside the constructor.

What is the way to test the conditions inside such a constructor with gtest?

Comment: If you want to test your constructor, you may throw inside it in case of error, and test there is no throw.
You might want to redesign to take some argument as `stream` or other interface to allow to mock it and have better control to test your class.

Comment: I concur with previous commenter. Use dependency injection and inject a real object or a mock that does or emulates the actual file opening.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Quick answer is: there is noway given the information you provided.

If however the file handle you opened, or any related flag/variable, is protected, one technique with gtest is to inherit from your class and use the derived class to access that data, and test it.

As a side note, constructors should not do stuffs: in your example, imagine that for any reason the filesystem does not allow you to open the file. How does this affect the class behavior? You cannot state. Therefore you may have undefined behavior from your class and you do not have any control on it.
Even worse is the *throw exception* suggestion, for the same reason. Use dependency injection in your constructor or make your class a template class in such a way that you can control the injected policy.

Comment: Throwing exceptions inside a constructor to indicate error conditions is a standard and accepted coding pattern

Comment: @Smeetheey: there is a pletora of discussion on this on the web. Throwing an exception is the standard _but_ you have to remember to catch it from the outside, that is, you have to assume a side effect from your class constructor. Using an `init()` method is valid, but then you have to take care in multithreading environment. In bpth cases you have to do something on the outside, but if you throw in constructor, you have to assume a behavior not present in the class API. This is some sort of taste.

Comment: Yes, it is a matter of choice. Both approaches are valid, people can have preference for one or the other. So I disagree with your invalidation of the throw approach in your answer. Also: *"As a side note, constructors should not do stuff"* - again this is an opinion (one that flies in the face of those who believe in RAII) stated as accepted fact.

Comment: The question is about testing this behavior with gtest. Throwing an exception does not allow to test in the sense gtest is meant to use. So, even if throwing is valid in general, it is outside the world of gtest purpose and use.

Comment: Disagree again. You can test exception behaviour with `EXPECT_THROW` and `EXPECT_NO_THROW`. I have done this in the past precisely to test constructor behaviour.

Comment: You can EXPECT_THROW on methods.

Comment: And what if you need to instantiate your class in a shared pointer in other sides of your code, for example? You need to do one more integration test just because you want to throw exceptions in constructors. Good luck.

Comment: You can use `EXPECT_THROW` on any statement, not just methods. For example: `MyClass* pMy; EXPECT_ANY_THROW(pMy = new MyClass();)` or (with braces for multiple statements) `EXPECT_ANY_THROW({MyClass myc; myc.someOp();})`

Comment: @Smeeheey can you write a proper answer about all the points that you are stating here? It will be helpful.

Comment: @Smeeheey: look at this: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9c340dd656065894. Try the case with and without the shared pointer. Then imagine that the class under test comes from a library.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not showing me what you meant to show. In your live example, the `try` version with `shared_ptr` - when I uncomment it, it doesn't print "in catch", is that your point? Well that's because you're calling default constructor of `shared_ptr`, which just initiates the underlying pointer to null and doesn't create an `S`. If you call it with `new S`, you get the catch behaviour. Also, its better to use (in particular for exception safety) `make_shared`. Corrected code [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6fcdb27680984835) - all `try`s work